# Why I cannot select the specific Game object?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to increase my game which is select(you can se below), but unfortunately my selection not working it throws an exception.

I want to make the following sql query:

```
Select * from Games
where userId = 3
order by createdAt desc
```

gameController.js:

```
exports.increaseScore = async (req, res) => {
    const userId = res.userId;

    try {
        const game = await Game.findOne({ where: { userId: userId } }, { limit: 1, order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']] });
        game.score += 1;
        await game.save();
        res.status(200).json("Score increased successfully!");
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
};
```

gameModell.js:

```
const Game = sequelize.define("Games", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    score: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    difficulty: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
});

exports.Game = Game;
```

Relations between game and user:

```
const userModel = require('./models/user');
const gameModel = require('./models/game');

userModel.hasMany(gameModel.Game, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
gameModel.Game.belongsTo(userModel, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indicated the options other than `where` as a second argument to `findOne` though you need to indicate them all in the first one:

```js
const game = await Game.findOne({
  where: { userId: userId },
//  limit: 1,
  order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]
});
```

Also there is no need to indicate `limit` because `findOne` already does it automatically (that's why its name is about `one` on contrary to `findAll`).